# OpenCL clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer with stride

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have an OpenCL buffer containing an 2D image.
This image have stride bigger than its width.
I need to make OpenCL image from this buffer.
The problem is that function `clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer` does not contain stride as an input parameter.
Is it possible to make OpenCL image from OpenCL buffer(with stride bigger than width), with only one copying or faster?
The one way to solve this problem is to write own kernel, but maybe there are much more neat solutions?

Comment: I don't know an "out of the box" solution, but think that it might be worth considering copying the relevant part of the buffer with `clEnqueueCopyBufferRect` into a new buffer, and copying *this* buffer into an image. Although this involves *two* copying operations, it could be simpler than writing an own kernel. And considering that the copy operation is completely left to the OpenCL implementation, I think that is is not unlikely that it is not much *slower* than an own kernel (but, maybe, potentially, even *faster*...)

Comment: I like the CopyBufferRect then CopyBufferToImage solution; it's going to be faster than the line-by-line CopyImageToBuffer suggested below. However, I'll ask: _What's wrong with including the extra pixels in the image?_ You're already dealing with them for your buffer, so they're probably not a huge amount of extra data, and you'd still access your image using the same coordinates whether they are there or not. The next operation you run on the image can be to a correctly-sized one.

Comment: I can't include extra pixels into image because I use image sampler to process borders with mirroring and bilinear interpolation. The compute resources are very limited to run own implementation of bi-linear interpolation with border mirroring.

Comment: @Dithermaster @Marco13 I had thought of the `clEnqueueCopyBufferRect` method too, but my first thought was that the extra copy would kill performance. I was very wrong however, and I've updated my answer with some performance results for the three different approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method in the OpenCL specification which allows you to directly create an image from a buffer when the buffer data has a stride not equal to the image width. The most efficient solution would probably be to write your own kernel to do this.

The simplest solution that doesn't involve writing your own kernel would be to copy one line at a time with `clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage`. If your image is big enough, it might be that the performance of this technique would be reasonably comparable to the hand-written kernel, but you would have to try it out to see.

---

I didn't include the `clEnqueueCopyBufferRect` approach in my original answer because my first instinct was that the extra copy would kill performance. However, the comments above got me thinking about it further, and I was interested enough to implement all three approaches to see what the performance was actually like.

[image: performance results]

As I suspected, the fastest approach was to implement a kernel to do this directly. However, copying the data over line-by-line was significantly slower than I had anticipated. Copying the buffer into an intermediate buffer with `clEnqueueCopyBufferRect` is actually a pretty good compromise of performance and simplicity, although is still a couple of times slower than the kernel implementation.

The source code for this little experiment can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jrprice/11343623). I was copying a 1020x1020 image with a stride of 1024, and the timings are averaged over 8 runs.

Comment: Excellent analysis (+1). Except for the Xeon case, the time of the "rect" solution seems to be "*roughly* twice of the kernel time", which intuitively makes sense, since this is all only about data being transferred within device memory - either once ... or twice.